# L'Hopital's Rule proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

Stephen Abbott's Analysis introduces L'Hopital's Rule of the form $0/0$ as follows:

**Theorem:** Let $f,g$ be continuous on an interval containing $a$, and assume $f,g$ are differentiable on this interval, except possibly at $a$. If $f(a)=g(a)=0$ and $g'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \neq a$, then
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a } \dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = L \implies \lim_{x \rightarrow a} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} =L.$$

Abbott then claims that the proof involves a straightforward application of Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem, and leaves it as an exercise. I have managed to come up with a proof, and I would like to  check if the argument is valid.

**Proof:**
Let $I$ be the interval, and let $\epsilon > 0$. By assumption, there exists $\delta >0$ such that $x \in I$ and $\lvert x-a \rvert < \delta$ implies $\left \lvert \dfrac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} - L \right \rvert < \epsilon$. Choose this $\delta$. First consider $x \in (a-\delta,a)$. By Cauchy's Mean Value Theorem, $\exists \ c \in (x,a)$ such that $(f(a)-f(x))\ g'(c) = (g(a)-g(x)) \ f'(c).$ Since $g'$ is non-zero on $(x,a)$,
$$\dfrac{f'(c)}{g'(c)} = \dfrac{f(a)-f(x)}{g(a)-g(x)}=\dfrac{-f(x)}{-g(x)}=\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}.$$
But $\left \lvert \dfrac{f'(c)}{g'(c)} - L \right \rvert < \epsilon \implies \left \lvert \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} - L \right \rvert < \epsilon $. Since $a-\delta < x<a$ implies $\left \rvert \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} - L \right \rvert < \epsilon$, it follows that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow a^-} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} =L$.

Similarly, considering $x \in (a,a+\delta)$, we can easily adapt the above proof to conclude that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} =L$ too. Since both the left and right hand limits exist and are equal to L, we have that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \rightarrow a} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} =L$.